# "I sit and watch the children play"... is that correct?

Tags: word-in-context

Is the phrase "I sit and watch the children play" in the Rolling Stones song "As tears go by" correct?

I mean, the correct wouldn't be to say "I sit and watch the children to play"?

Comment: Yes, “I sit and watch the children play” is correct. Using ‘to play’ does not make any sense to me.

Comment: That's correct, after some verbs like watch hear see, you can use bare infinitive to imply a completed action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they have different meanings,
"I sit and watch the children play" means she/he sits while watching the children play.

"I sit and watch the children to play" this one means she/he watches the children as a way to play herself/himself, which is weird and doesn't make too much sense

Comment: As an alternative pair of sentences illustrating the same semantic / syntactic shift, without needing so much contrivance to make the second version seem comprehensible, consider ***I watch him learn*** (I watch and ***he*** learns) and ***I watch him to learn*** (I watch and ***I*** learn).